# Only first value in function with multiple nested loops

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, indentation

I'm quite new to Python and I'm running into a very basic problem.
I've written a function with multiple `for` loops and an `if` statement.
This code when run separately shows all values that I expect.
However when put it into a `def` function it returns only the first value.
I know it has something to do with indentation and using `yield` instead of `return` in the function. However trying to resolve it with both options still gives one result back.
Below is the sample of the code:

```
def generate_body(objectFr, properties):
objFrame = objectFr
data = properties

for obj in objFrame.Object_Naam:
    properties = data.loc[data['Objects'] == obj, 'attribuut_naam'].dropna()
    # minOccur = data.loc[data['Objects'] == obj, 'minOccurs'].dropna()
    
    for prop in properties:
        last = properties.iloc[-1]
        first = properties.iloc[0]
        jsonbody = []
        # bodystring = ''.join(jsonbody)
        if prop == first:
            jsonbody.append('"' + obj + '",' + ' "type": "object,"' + ' "properties": {' + str(prop) + '"' + ': { "type": "string" }' )
        elif prop == last:
            jsonbody.append('"' + str(prop) + '"' + ': { "type": "string" }' )
        else:
            jsonbody.append('"' + str(prop) + '"' + ': { "type": "string" },' )
        
    return ''.join(jsonbody)
```

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Your indentation shows that the loop will return after the first iteration of `for obj in objFrame.Object_Naam:`. Also, `jsonbody` will overwrite every time the second loop runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things:
The indentation under the `def` is out of place.
The return statement must be out of the `for` loop.
Put the `jsonbody[]` in the right place.

Try this:

```
def generate_body(objectFr, properties):
    objFrame = objectFr
    data = properties
    jsonbody = []

    for obj in objFrame.Object_Naam:
        properties = data.loc[data['Objects'] == obj, 'attribuut_naam'].dropna()
        # minOccur = data.loc[data['Objects'] == obj, 'minOccurs'].dropna()
    
        for prop in properties:
            last = properties.iloc[-1]
            first = properties.iloc[0]
            
            # bodystring = ''.join(jsonbody)
            if prop == first:
                jsonbody.append('"' + obj + '",' + ' "type": "object,"' + ' "properties": {' + str(prop) + '"' + ': { "type": "string" }' )
            elif prop == last:
                jsonbody.append('"' + str(prop) + '"' + ': { "type": "string" }' )
            else:
                jsonbody.append('"' + str(prop) + '"' + ': { "type": "string" },' )
        
    return ''.join(jsonbody)
```

Comment: unfortunately the suggestion still returns one value

Comment: He can't upvote yet, the first `def` indentation issue is due to stackoverflow's tab-based code blocks, which is super annoying. Idk why they don't recommend the ``` style of code blocks.